# I get an Error when I try to use Firebase Auth

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm Building my first time a website thats include firebase (firebase auth).
I get an Error when I run my HTML Code in the Browser.

> Uncaught TypeError: firebase.auth is not a function
> at HTMLButtonElement. (app.js:24)

I dont find any articels too this issue.
I've already reinstalled node and the firebase tools.
Has anybody an answer for me, I really dont know whats to do...
Heres my Index.html file and my App.js File
Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Log In Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.9/firebase-app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Main-Div">
        <h3 class="Headline">
            Do you have an Account?
        </h3>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email..." class="AccountInput" type="email" id="txtemail">
    </br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Passcode..." class="AccountInput" type="Password" id="txtpassword">
    </br>
        <button class="LogInButton" id="1Button">Log In</button>
        <button class="SignUpButton" id="2Button">Sign Up now!</button>
        <button class="LogOutButton" id="3Button">Log Out</button>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here my other File, App.js: (i've censored the datas about my firebase-database)

```
(function(){
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "Censored",
    authDomain: "Censored",
    projectId: "Censored",
    storageBucket: "Censored",
    messagingSenderId: "Censored",
    appId: "Censored"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Get Elements
  const txtEmail = document.getElementById('txtemail');
  const txtPassword = document.getElementById('txtpassword');
  const btnLogIn = document.getElementById('1Button');
  const btnSignUp = document.getElementById('2Button');
  const btnLogOut = document.getElementById('3Button');

  btnLogIn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const email = txtEmail.value;
    const password = txtPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();

    const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
    promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
  });

}());
```

Thanks for your attention
Greetings
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `index.html` you imported only the core firebase library `firebase-app.js` in order to use a firebase service (firestore/storage etc) in your web app, you need to import that respective service from a CDN.

in your case, you need to add `firebase-auth.js` in your `<head></head>`

here is the link

```js
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.8/firebase-auth.js"></script>
```

in this [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#from-the-cdn) you can find all of the services CDNs

also you need to go to your project's firebase dashboard and enable password authentication as stated in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#before_you_begin)

Comment: sorry for the delay, that error is obvious, go to line 25 in your code editor and look for 'pass', you will realize that you named the varible 'password' and not 'pass'